# Laravel returns 1/0 instead of boolean value from pivot table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i have a pivot table that has a boolean type column

```
$table->boolean('is_activated')->default(true);
```

this column's data is stored in the database as integer values 1/0 not as true or false as it should be , is there any solutions other than casting it in the model class as boolean because since it's a pivot table it's not actually needed to create a model for it

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not have built-in Boolean type. However, it uses TINYINT(1) instead. To make it more convenient, MySQL provides BOOLEAN or BOOL as the synonym of TINYINT(1).

In MySQL, zero is considered as false, and non-zero value is considered as true. To use Boolean literals, you use the constants TRUE and FALSE that evaluate to 1 and 0 respectively. See the following example:

```
SELECT true, false, TRUE, FALSE, True, False;
-- 1 0 1 0 1 0
```

you do not have to cast for pivot table. just use it as it is.